# Convert HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf, docker in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf in my ASP.NET Core app.
I've added a wkhtmltopdf.exe to my project and marked as a Copy to an output to always.

Here's my code:

```
var htmlContent = receiptBody;
var wkhtmltopdf = new FileInfo(@"/app/Configuration/Wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe");
var converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter(wkhtmltopdf);
var pdfBytes = converter.ConvertToPdf(htmlContent);
```

The file has been founded but on:

```
var pdfBytes = converter.ConvertToPdf(htmlContent);
```

I'm getting an error:

> System.Exception: Cannot generate PDF: Broken pipe --->
> System.IO.IOException: Broken pipe

I run my app using Docker and here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.2 ARG source WORKDIR /app 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://project-test:80 
EXPOSE 80 
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} . 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install-y libgdiplus 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectTest.dll"]
```

Maybe should somehow install wkhtmltopdf for linux?

Comment: How do you propose you run a windows binary on linux?

Comment: I would like to somehow run wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Try downloading the linux binary and running that the way you are trying to run the windows one! :) -- Linux binaries don't usually have file extensions, in case you didn't know

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code works fine for me with the latest .net core 6.0.1 image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.1-bullseye-slim AS base
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y libgdiplus
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdiplus.so
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zlib1g fontconfig libfreetype6 libx11-6 libxext6 libxrender1 wget gdebi
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN gdebi --n wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN apt install libssl1.1
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/libwkhtmltox.so /usr/lib/libwkhtmltox.so

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["docgen/docgen.csproj", "docgen/"]
RUN dotnet restore "docgen/docgen.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/docgen"
RUN dotnet build "docgen.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "docgen.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "docgen.dll"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should download files [wkhtmltopdf for linux](https://github.com/fpanaccia/Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore/tree/master/Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore/Rotativa/Linux) and copy to output publish.

Also, give permissions to these files with this step in dockerfile

```
RUN chmod 755 ./wkhtmltopdf/Linux/wkhtmltopdf
RUN chmod 755 ./wkhtmltopdf/Linux/wkhtmltoimage
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about platform and binaries.

You can generate your own docker image with WKHTMLTOPDF and use it.

In my opinion, it is a cleaner way.

Here is a simple example:

1. Download WkHtmlToPdf - Debian 10 (Buster) - amd64 file:
   https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
2. Put downloaded .deb file into "deps" subfolder below where the Dockerfile is
3. Add WkHtmlToPdf installation into the Dockerfile.

Make sure the download .deb filename matches the line:

```
ENV WKHTMLTOX wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb
```

And ensure the .NET Core images use Debian Buster.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /app

## copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore

## copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /app/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

## START - INSTALL WKHTMLTOPDF
ENV WKHTMLTOX wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb
ENV BUILD_PACKAGES build-essential
ENV MAIN_PACKAGES fontconfig libfreetype6 libjpeg62-turbo libxext6 libpng16-16 libx11-6 libxcb1  libxrender1 xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base 

COPY deps/$WKHTMLTOX ./

RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -yq $BUILD_PACKAGES $MAIN_PACKAGES \
    && dpkg -i ${WKHTMLTOX} \
    && apt-get remove -y $BUILD_PACKAGES \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && rm -rf ${WKHTMLTOX} \
    && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log
## END - INSTALL WKHTMLTPDF

COPY --from=build /app/aspnetapp/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

The INSTALL WKHTMLTOPDF code is based on:
https://gist.github.com/berkayakcay/1e4f0a355437f0db9c94935aa52283d2

The Dockerfile itself is based on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-dockerfile-1

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you add the line after WORKDIR/app:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install libgdiplus libc6-dev
```

For more info check https://github.com/fpanaccia/Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore