# Unable to load native library. The platform may be missing native dependencies (libjpeg62, etc). Or the current platform is not supported

Tags: docker, .net-core, wkhtmltopdf

I am having this error
 `Unable to load native library. The platform may be missing native dependencies (libjpeg62, etc). Or the current platform is not supported` from my docker image running .Net Core 6

My docker install for Wkhtml dependencies looks like this;

```
RUN apt-get update -qq 

RUN apt-get install -y fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libbsd0 \
libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libjpeg62-turbo libmd0 libpng16-16 \
libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxrender1 sensible-utils \
ucf x11-common xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev


RUN apt-get -qy install --no-install-recommends wget
RUN wget -nv -O /tmp/wkhtmltox.deb https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-2/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.bullseye_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get -qy install /tmp/wkhtmltox.deb


RUN cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
RUN cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin


RUN  wget http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/libj/libjpeg6b/libjpeg62_6b2-3_amd64.deb

RUN apt-get -y autoremove libjpeg62-turbo

RUN dpkg -i libjpeg62_6b2-3_amd64.deb

RUN apt --fix-broken install
```

As you can See I am even uninstalling `libjpeg62-turbo` and instead installing the older `libjpeg62`

**NOTE**

I am using microsofts image :
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base`
which is a debian based image

I am stuck and I don't know how to fix this problem, hoping I can get assisted with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same trouble, actually, the solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70414848/19536096

I've just replaced this line

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.1-bullseye-slim AS base
```

for

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```

And this line

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.1 AS build
```

for

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
```

Test it, and let me know if works for you as well.